# Selenium : Click on object with xpath not working

Tags: selenium

`XML` Snap shot :

```
<img id="reg_img_304316340" class="btnimg" style="top:0px; left:0px;
width:23px; height:140px;" title="Show Application List" 
alt="Show Application List" arimgcenter="1" artxt="Show Application List" aralttxt="1" 
src="../../../../imagepool/transparent_remedyappdc1?cid=1">
```

I am trying the below code , which is not working

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='reg_img_304316340']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='reg_img_304316340']")).click();
```

Please correct if any thing needs an update

Comment: What you mean "code not working"? Add exception log if you have any

Comment: Also let us know if element's `id` is dynamic (check whether it changed after page refresh)

Comment: Try once as `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img.btnimg[title='Show Application List']")).click();` and let me know..

Answer (score 0):

if id is not dynamic try java script executor to click on element

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("reg_img_304316340"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: This is not the right solution.It's just a hack for clicking an element when there is no other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `id` attribute value is dynamic here, you should try with different locator.

I would suggest, try using `By.cssSelector()` as below :-

```
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("img.btnimg[title='Show Application List']"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

//div[@id='divld9T-MckddA']/div[@class='item-img']/a[@class='imgObject']/img

Please specify the classes or identifiers of the tags inside the parent element
as shown above in example the img element is the one to be clicked. The ids in my case were dynamically generated